# Environment URL's for testing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm sure this is a common requirement. I have written an ASP.NET app but now I have testing requirements. Basically the application uses webservices and as such currently these are in the code. I need to be able to run the same aplpication using test URL's in as simple way as possible.

I was thinking I could put the URL's in the web.config and comment/uncomment the the variable as required.

I was thinking however how is this done in windows apps. I know that some applications, you specify on the command line when launching the env (e.g. prod, uat, prl) and the application then uses the relevant URL's - I presume this isnt done with if/else statements everywhere?

if(UAT){URL=app.settings["UATURL"]}

Any information on how this is done in a professional application for testing is appreciated.

Comment: Wrap a settings manager around all your configuration calls - let this do the checking of what environment you are in. No need to have `if` statements all over the place, put it into one manager class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create build configuration and use Web.Config transformation for the different environments as descripted [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c17407/ASPNET-Tutorial-WebConfig-Transformation.htm)

If you have your build configurations you can also use the C# Preprocessor Directives #if like for example this:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your head tag:

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/optionalInnerPath/" target="_blank" />
</head>
```

Specify your site path in the href attribute and all the paths in your site will be relative to this path.

Comment: He's referring to webservices, this is only handy for client-side things like images and links.